# Rails better way to use array in raw postgres query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am writing raw query in rails and executing it with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Is there any better way to convert this?:

```
completions.type IN ('#{params[:certification].join("','")}')
```

where

```
params[:certification]
#=> ['Gold', 'Platinum']
```

and I want it to be like

```
completions.type IN ('Gold', 'Platinum')
```

Same way Active record does

```
Completion.where(type: ['Gold', 'Platinum'])
```

This is my query which I can't write with active record

```
SELECT type, json_array_elements(
              replace(
                (completions::json)::character varying,
                'null',
                '[]'
              )::json) AS completions_json
FROM completions 
WHERE completions.type IN ('#{params[:certification].join("','")}') 
AND (
  date(completions_json->>'completed_at')
    BETWEEN date('2015-10-01')
    AND     date('2015-12-01')
)
```

Comment: https://owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @Зелёный that's why I am searching for a way such that I don't need to interpolate the values

Comment: duplicate of your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975247/is-there-a-way-to-pass-params-to-postgres-raw-query-in-rails

Comment: I asked that one later more generalized

Answer (score 0):

From: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions

```
Client.where(orders_count: [1,3,5])
```

so in your case:

```
Completions.where(type: params[:certification])
```

Assuming that you are using an active record model; with raw queries your milage may vary.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but I can't use active record query this way

Comment: can you explain briefly why you can't use ActiveRecord this way? Is it flat out not available in your project? Perhaps you are using a different type of database? Context is worth 100 IQ points...

Comment: The question asks about a raw query. There are uncountable reasons to use raw queries in Rails since its ActiveRecord implementation only handles simple, trivial cases.