# Is there a way to pass params to postgres raw query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a **complex** raw query where I want to pass params instead of interpolating them

**Ex:**

```
query = 
  "SELECT id, abbr as code, name
   FROM states
   WHERE name IN ('#{params[:state].join("','")}')"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Is there any way to pass params like the ActiveRecord does

```
State.where(name: ['Alabama', 'Alaska'])
```

Comment: I do not believe there is such a thing. Adding this as a comment rather than an answer because you can't prove a negative. You can, however, represent your query with Arel--it has a lot more power in terms of lining up with SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql):

```
Post.find_by_sql(["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id, start_date])

[#<Post:0x36bff9c @attributes={"title"=>"The Cheap Man Buys Twice"}>, ...]
```